# Mouse and keyboard not doing anything when logging in to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

I have faced issues such as being unable to tune brightness, booting to a black screen, and the like since I downloaded Linux. Now my mouse and keyboard won't accept input when logging in.

I have tried booting into recovery mode and doing `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

- *Device*: Lenovo ideapad Gaming
- *CPU*: AMD radeon graphics 4800
- *GPU*: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650Ti

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: are you using the Nvidia graphics or the AMD graphics? which graphics drivers do you have installed?

Comment: I got same problem, xorg log says nothing except Mouse and keyboard are turned off

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue please any fix do you found ?